# Python defaultdict(list) behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, defaultdict

I was playing around with Chatgpt and it kind of suprised me that if you declare

```
node = defaultdict(list)
node['xyz'] = 'xyz'
```

adding a new string key-value pair. I thought node will create a new list when 'xyz' key doesn't present in the node, therefore if you assign A string to [], it will probably return a runtime error or something. But this one actually works, according to gpt. Any reason why this works? are there any docs I can read up about this?

Comment: Well, why not start with the official Python documentation, rather than the output of a tool that was never built to provide true and accurate information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collections.defaultdict` will automatically return an empty list (assuming `list` is the provided `default_factory`) if you *access* a missing key, but will behave like a normal dictionary otherwise.

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

> Return a new dictionary-like object. `defaultdict` is a subclass of the
> built-in `dict` class. It overrides one method and adds one writable
> instance variable. The remaining functionality is the same as for the
> `dict` class and is not documented here.
>
> The first argument provides the initial value for the `default_factory`
> attribute; it defaults to `None`. All remaining arguments are treated
> the same as if they were passed to the `dict` constructor, including
> keyword arguments.
>
> `defaultdict` objects support the following method in addition to the
> standard dict operations:
>
> **`__missing__(key)`**
>
> If the default_factory attribute is `None`, this raises a `KeyError` exception with the key as argument.
>
> If `default_factory` is not `None`, it is called without arguments to
> provide a default value for the given key, this value is inserted in
> the dictionary for the key, and returned.
>
> If calling `default_factory` raises an exception this exception is
> propagated unchanged.
>
> This method is called by the `__getitem__()` method of the dict class
> when the requested key is not found; whatever it returns or raises is
> then returned or raised by `__getitem__()`.
>
> Note that `__missing__()` is not called for any operations besides
> `__getitem__()`. This means that `get()` will, like normal dictionaries, return `None` as a default rather than using `default_factory`.

Answer (score 2):

The default part only comes into play if you try to READ a key that doesn't exist.  You can override any key with any type you want.

Comment: And more precisely, only if you try to read it via bracketed access (`mydict[key]`). It won't trigger if you try to read it via `.get` or `.setdefault` or `.pop` or the like.